# Interacting with Unicode characters in Firefox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, unicode

What I want to achieve: hovering over a unicode character should toggle the visibility of another span element. Works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

I have the following HTML:

```
<span class="default" id="some_id">
    <b id="another_id">&#8416;</b>
</span>
<span id="even_another_id" style="margin-left: 10px; display:none;">
    Some text.
</span>
```

And when I try to use the following JS (with jQuery) in Chrome (Version 37) it works, but in Firefox (Version 31) it doesn't:

```
$("#some_id").hover(function () {
    $('#even_another_id').toggle();
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvc9v/) to elaborate the problem.

I've already tried using the other (inner) IDs for the event and also tried with the mouseover event, the mouseenter/mouseleave events. Nothing worked. Even a simple click event doesn't work.

Is this a bug in Firefox or am I just doing something wrong?

EDIT:

I've even tried it with the CSS property :hover now. Same result. Chrome works, Firefox doesn't.

**EDIT after correct anwer:** here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvc9v/2/) that is also working in Firefox!

> Blockquote

Comment: Your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvc9v/) works for me in Firefox 31.0 .. Have you tried checking browser console? Clearing cookies/cache?

Comment: I get exactly the same behaviour in Chrome and in Firefox (latest stable versions on Windows 7). Furthermore, your code does nothing specific to text. I'm pretty sure the error (whatever it is) is somewhere else. Have you checked the JavaScript console for error messages?

Comment: @urbz Yes I've done that already. Didn't change the result.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario The console does not show a single error or warning.

Comment: Try [Firefox's Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode). I've sometimes seen third-party extensions completely breaking pages.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Sadly, that also didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U+20E0 Combining Enclosing Circle Backslash, as a combining character, is meant to go over the top of a preceding character. Consequently it has no width of its own, and so the `<span>` that contains it also has zero width. So there is no area for you to mouse over. It's not Firefox-specific, though different browsers have different font preferences, which might choose different renderings.

You could reserve some space for it by putting a non-breaking space before it, eg:

```
<span ...>&#x00A0;&#x20E0;</span>
```

But still, using U+20E0 on the web is dicey as font support is poor. (I get a glyph-not-known box as no fonts on my browser support it. At least the box takes up space so is hoverable!) More common visually-similar alternatives you could perhaps try are `∅` (U+2205 Empty Set symbol) or `Ø` U+00D8 Latin Capital Letter With Stroke. Otherwise to be sure just use an image.